# After building and running asp.net website my page get refreshed automatically one time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net 
I have created a small web site in visual studio 2010 using asp.net and C#.
whenever i run the website it get refreshed one time automatically.

I have not used any meta tag refresh attribute.

why this happening, Please help.....

Comment: What do you mean refreshed one time only? Do you mean after you click a button, it refreshes?
 
Tell us a bit more.

Comment: code please...wat u mean 1 time refresh?? u mean postback?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: no i have not any button on my page. 
I have created a new website by selecting File -> New -> Website -> ASP.Net Website - C#.

I build it and then run it.
When Default.aspx page is loaded it get refreshed after 2-3 second automatically. what could be the resons??

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue rather than a code one. Try checking your browser extensions and settings, something may be conflicting with the default.aspx page. Try pressing F12 as well and check the console. It will tell you if something is going wrong.

Comment: Does it happen on more than one browser?

Comment: @MightyLampshade, Thank you very much dude, It was browser's issue.
I updated my browser. It works fine now.

Comment: No problem, I'll post it as the answer so people see it easily :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a browser issue rather than a code one. Try checking your browser extensions and settings, something may be conflicting with the default.aspx page. Try pressing F12 as well and check the console. It will tell you if something is going wrong.